# How to use of present perfect or present simple in future time clause?

Tags: meaning, grammar, tenses, syntactic-analysis, clauses

I don't understand how difference is  between present simple and present perfect in future time clause?

For instance,

> - I will go out when I finish my assignment.
> - I will go out when I have finished my assignment.

Comment: There is no meaning difference in the sentences you provide. There is a difference in construction, but the meaning is the same.

Comment: In both examples, the two clauses have their own lives. That is, *will go* is future, but that event depends on looking back and seeing that my assignment is complete. 
Also, I will go out when I find out whether Pompeii ended well, a long time ago.

Comment: What makes you think those are different?

Comment: I wouldn't immediately think of these two similar constructions as having the same meaning... (1) *I will be nervous when I see him,* (2) *I will be nervous when I **have seen** him*.

Comment: @tchrist Tense in the time clause is different so that make me think so.

Comment: @JohnLawler Not quite true, I'd say; there is the same difference as between any other comparable sentences using the simple present and the perfect present in juxtaposition. _When_ denotes a moment or stretch of time, which can either be the moment/stretch when the action in the verb is carried out (present simple), or the stretch of time when the state of having completed that action applies to the subject. With a verb like _finish_, which signifies almost the same as the perfect itself, the difference becomes less pronounced, but there is still the distinction that “when I finish” is a ->

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’m thinking that here *when* means *after* or *once*. I can't see any difference between *after I finish* and *after I have finished*: both are in the present tense and I can't see the perfective aspect changing anything. On the other hand, *after I finished* is different.

Comment: -> _point in time_, whereas “when I have finished” is a _period of time_. If I go out when I finish my dinner, I leave immediately upon putting down my knife and fork; if I go out when I have finished it, I leave at some point after putting down my knife and fork, during an unspecified period while I'm in a state of ‘having finished’ eating.

Comment: @Janus: That's what I meant (of course, you can ***see*** someone for an extended period, but usually you ***finish*** something at a specific point in time).

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are other punctual verbs that would work differently: “I'll make up my mind when I meet him” and “I'll make up my mind when I've met him” are more standard point vs period examples. The trouble here is _finish_ (and similar verbs) specifically, since it means close to the same thing as using the perfect aspect does.

Comment: @Janus: (man doing bodywork on his car, to son who wants to "help") *I'll do the welding on my own, but you can help with the fine sanding and painting when we finish the job.* It's just about possible to contrive contexts where the (final) process of "finishing" something extends over time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Marginally perhaps… but I would find a progressive “when we’re finishing up/the job” much more natural in your example.

Comment: @Janus: Well, we've always got ***while*** and ***once*** as non-ambiguous alternatives to ***when*** in such contexts. Offhand I can't easily think of any common usages where people *deliberately* exploit that ambiguity, but I wouldn't be surprised to learn of one.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Do you mean present perfect in future time clause give meaning the next action is not neccessary to be done immediately after previous action is done?                For me , recently I have understanded present perfect in future time clause uses when the next action is done immediately after the previous action is done.

Comment: @PiggieVeggie Yes, that's essentially what I mean. Think about it this way: you finished your assignment five minutes ago. You can now say “I have finished my assignment”, because you are in the state where your assignment is finished. In three hours, you can still say “I have finished my assignment” and be correct, because that state continues. Your assignment doesn't become unfinished. Same thing in the future here. If you go out two hours after finishing, you're still in the state of having finished. What limits this is whether it's relevant to compare the thing you're talking about ->

Comment: -> (that is, going out) to finishing your assignment. “I have graduated high school” is still as true for me now as it was in 2002; but it wouldn't have made much sense for me to say I was “going out when I've finished high school” two weeks before graduation if I meant that I was going out tonight, 15 years later. There's no connection anymore.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Why don't you post a single answer instead of posting dozens of comments?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. There is indirect support in the _Cambridge Grammar of English_ for your contention that the two sentences permit different interpretations. In comparing the simple past and past perfect, the CGE states: "_The past simple often suggests a more immediate causal link between two events, compared with the past perfect:_ When he opened his desk he discovered a dead bird (_stresses the immediate result, rather than_ 'When he had opened his desk ... ')".

Answer (score 1):

To the average person on the street these two answers would have the same meaning regardless of their different verb structures.

However, I think there is a **subtle** difference which is more technical that practical.

The first  using the simple form might be given if the person was asked the following **question:**

**John, when are you coming out?**

John's answer uses the simple form because he is stating the **fact** that he will go out (for sure) but he possibly has some other things to do in the meantime like playing soccer, etc. **BUT** it (the assignment) will be finished.  He just doesn't know when.

John would probably answer using the present perfect form if the same question is asked while he is sitting at his desk working on his assignment with no intention to do anything else until he finishes it and then  he goes out.
He was working on the assignment before the point in time before he was asked the question and will no doubt continue up to the point where he will get up and go out.

Some help from Martin Parrots book:' Grammar for English Language Teachers